# Jenkins - Why my tests in parallel don't finish the same way as sequential

Tags: jenkins, docker-compose

I'm running tests from my Jenkins and I've realized that if I run one only test, the result is SUCCESS; but if I run three tests in parallel, that test doesn't finish SUCCESS, it gets timeout.

My docker configuration is:

```
version: "2"

services:
  selenium:
    networks:
      mynet:
        ipv4_address: 172.25.0.100
    image: bufete/spider-selenium:beta1
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  hub:
    networks:
      mynet:
        ipv4_address: 172.25.0.101
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - "5001:4444"
    environment:
      - GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT=1400
      - GRID_MAX_SESSION=10
      - GRID_TIMEOUT=120
      - GRID_NEW_SESSION_WAIT_TIMEOUT=-1
#      - GRID_TIMEOUT=900
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug:3.3.1
    shm_size: 2g
    links:
      - hub
    volumes:
      - /dev/urandom:/dev/random
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=172.25.0.101
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
      - NODE_MAX_SESSION=1
      - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=1
      - SCREEN_WIDTH=1920
      - SCREEN_HEIGHT=1480
      - GRID_TIMEOUT=120
      - no_proxy=""
    networks:
      - mynet
#    ports:
#      - "666:5900"
    volumes:
      - "/dev/shm:/dev/shm"
```

In Jenkins, I execute the following command:

```
cd folder_project/name_test/
/opt/tools/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin/mvn -e test
```

Do you know how could I get the same result running my tests in parallel???

Thanks so much!!

Comment: How should that compose file help us to know, how you run the test in Jenkins?

Comment: I run the tests from my Jenkins server that use a docker (so I attach you the configuration file).

Comment: And what commands does Jenkins execute?

Comment: cd folder_project/name_test/  and the following: 
/opt/tools/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin/mvn -e test

Comment: I've added your question and added that info.

Comment: So the question remains.. what does maven do? How does this relate to your `docker-compose.yml`? Your question is so unclear that I just cannot guess what you actually do. I won't help any further, please take the time to formulate better questions. Thanks for understanding.